# Why to add a connection in routes file when using link_to in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, link-to

I was trying to accomplish the following:

> <%= link_to "Log out", { :controller
>   => 'users', :action => 'logout' }, :class => 'menulink2' %>

But it didn't work, it always redirected me to a show view. I had to had the following to my routes.rb:

> map.connect 'users/logout',
>   :controller => 'users', :action =>
>   'logout'

Why didn't rails recognize the action I was passing ('logout') ?

Comment: Isn't it a problem with the controller name?

Comment: weird, it's in conformity with http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/ Did you try using named routes?

Comment: yes, actually I included: "map.resources :usuarios" to my routes file in order to work with named routes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That logic has to be specified somewhere. There's got to be some mapping from the hash `{:controller => 'users', :action => 'logout'}` to a url, and the place that's done in rails is the `routes.rb` file. In older versions of rails many `routes.rb` came with a default at the end:

`map.connect ':controller(/:action/(:id(.:format)))'`

Which would make it so that most any :controller, :action hash could be specified and then routed to `host.url/:controller/:action`.

---

With the more modern versions resource-based routes are heavily favored, and controllers which don't follow rails' REST conventions (i.e. having only `:index,:show,:create,:new,:edit,:update,:destroy` methods) generally have to have their routes explicitly specified in some way.

(Either with `map.resources :users, :collection => {:get => :logout}` or with `map.connect( 'some_url', :controller => 'users', :action => 'logout'})`)

---

I'm guessing, but the reason they did that is probably that the actions of a controller are really just its public methods.

It's frequently nice to have public methods in your controllers that aren't url-end-points for testing purposes.

For instance, you could have `before_filter`s as public methods that you might want to test without having to use `@controller.send(:your_before_filter_method)` in your test code.

So they whitelist the resource actions, and make the others unreachable by default. Let me look through the rails changelog and see if I'm right.